# Creating a simple multiboot kernel loaded with grub2

Tags: assembly, x86, kernel, osdev, grub

I'm trying to follow the instructions here to build a simple OS kernel: http://mikeos.sourceforge.net/write-your-own-os.html

Except, instead of booting from a floppy, I want to create a grub-based ISO image and boot a multiboot CD in the emulator.   I've added the following to the source listed at that page, for the multiboot header:

```
MBALIGN     equ  1<<0                   ; align loaded modules on page boundaries
MEMINFO     equ  1<<1                   ; provide memory map
FLAGS       equ  MBALIGN | MEMINFO      ; this is the Multiboot 'flag' field
MAGIC       equ  0x1BADB002             ; 'magic number' lets bootloader find the header
CHECKSUM    equ -(MAGIC + FLAGS)        ; checksum of above, to prove we are multiboot
section .multiboot
align 4
    dd MAGIC
    dd FLAGS
    dd CHECKSUM
```

and I'm doing the following to create the image:

```
nasm -felf32 -o init.bin  init.s
cp init.bin target/boot/init.bin
grub2-mkrescue -o init.iso target/
```

Then I run qemu to boot it:

```
qemu-system-x86_64 -cdrom ./init.iso
```

After selecting 'myos' from the boot menu, I get the error

```
error: invalid arch-dependent ELF magic
```

What does that mean, and how can I fix it?   I tried messing with the elf format, but only `-felf32` seems to work...

Comment: (the grub.cfg has only a single menuitem with a multiboot pointing to the image)

Comment: You forgot to link your code into an executable.

Comment: @Jester - It's a boot block, not an executable. My understanding from the online tutorials (the one I linked included) was that you don't link it (what would it link against?).   If not - what command do you propose I use to "link" the ELF relocatable before putting it in the target/ directory?

Comment: (in particular if I use -f bin and copy the result directly (less the multiboot header) to the system area of the ISO, it gets entered just fine.   I want to use *grub2*, though... and its documentation for this stuff is horrid.)

Comment: (file init.bin: `init.bin: ELF 32-bit LSB relocatable, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), not stripped`)

Comment: The boot code in that page is 16 bit flat binary. That is fine for a BIOS boot sector. For a multiboot kernel you need a 32 bit ELF executable.

Comment: That makes no sense.  The whole point of multiboot is that you don't have to use a specific binary format.  And plenty of systems don't "do" ELF.   See:  https://www.gnu.org/software/grub/manual/multiboot/multiboot.html (esp section 1.6), or google 'booting non-Elf kernel with grub'.    The problem I'm having only seems to occur when I use an ISO / cd emulation - every other way of starting the kernel works fine...

Comment: (http://forum.osdev.org/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=21260 for example)

Comment: Indeed, **if** you use the **full** multiboot header, the code doesn't need to be in ELF, as in the forum post you linked.  But you don't, so grub tries to read the ELF info. See section 3.1.2.  Your code needs to be **fully linked**, and it needs to be **32 bit protected mode**. See section 3.2.

Comment: Minimal working example: https://github.com/cirosantilli/x86-bare-metal-examples/tree/d1f11492c2d2828c9c713d75b6f173da955aafc3/multiboot/hello-world

Answer (score 9, accepted):

GRUB supports *ELF32* and flat binaries. Your header though implicitly says that you are providing an *ELF* binary.

## Using Flat Binary with Multiboot

If you wish to tell the Multiboot loader (GRUB) that you are using a flat binary you must set *bit 16* to 1:

```
MULTIBOOT_AOUT_KLUDGE    equ  1 << 16
                              ;FLAGS[16] indicates to GRUB we are not
                              ;an ELF executable and the fields
                              ;header address,load address,load end address,
                              ;bss end address, and entry address will be
                              ;available in our Multiboot header
```

It isn't as simple as just specifying this flag. You must provide a complete Multiboot header that provides the Multiboot loader the information to load our binary into memory. When using *ELF* format this information is in the *ELF* header that precedes our code so didn't have to be explicitly provided. The Multiboot header is defined in the [GRUB documentation](http://www.gnu.org/software/grub/manual/multiboot/multiboot.html#Header-layout) in great detail.

When using *NASM* with `-f bin` it is important to note that we need to specify the origin point for our code. Multiboot loaders load our kernel at physical address `0x100000`. We must specify in our assembler file that our origin point is `0x100000` so that proper offsets etc. will get generated in our final flat binary image.

This is an example stripped and modified from one of my own projects that provides a simple header. The call to `_Main` is set up like a C call in the example, but you don't have to do it that way. Usually I call into a function that takes a couple parameters on the stack (using C calling convention).

```
[BITS 32]
[global _start]
[ORG 0x100000]                ;If using '-f bin' we need to specify the
                              ;origin point for our code with ORG directive
                              ;multiboot loaders load us at physical 
                              ;address 0x100000

MULTIBOOT_AOUT_KLUDGE    equ  1 << 16
                              ;FLAGS[16] indicates to GRUB we are not
                              ;an ELF executable and the fields
                              ;header address, load address, load end address;
                              ;bss end address and entry address will be available
                              ;in Multiboot header
MULTIBOOT_ALIGN          equ  1<<0   ; align loaded modules on page boundaries
MULTIBOOT_MEMINFO        equ  1<<1   ; provide memory map

MULTIBOOT_HEADER_MAGIC   equ  0x1BADB002
                              ;magic number GRUB searches for in the first 8k
                              ;of the kernel file GRUB is told to load

MULTIBOOT_HEADER_FLAGS   equ  MULTIBOOT_AOUT_KLUDGE|MULTIBOOT_ALIGN|MULTIBOOT_MEMINFO
CHECKSUM                 equ  -(MULTIBOOT_HEADER_MAGIC + MULTIBOOT_HEADER_FLAGS)

KERNEL_STACK             equ  0x00200000  ; Stack starts at the 2mb address & grows down

_start:
        xor    eax, eax                ;Clear eax and ebx in the event
        xor    ebx, ebx                ;we are not loaded by GRUB.
        jmp    multiboot_entry         ;Jump over the multiboot header
        align  4                       ;Multiboot header must be 32
                                       ;bits aligned to avoid error 13
multiboot_header:
        dd   MULTIBOOT_HEADER_MAGIC    ;magic number
        dd   MULTIBOOT_HEADER_FLAGS    ;flags
        dd   CHECKSUM                  ;checksum
        dd   multiboot_header          ;header address
        dd   _start                    ;load address of code entry point
                                       ;in our case _start
        dd   00                        ;load end address : not necessary
        dd   00                        ;bss end address : not necessary
        dd   multiboot_entry           ;entry address GRUB will start at

multiboot_entry:
        mov    esp, KERNEL_STACK       ;Setup the stack
        push   0                       ;Reset EFLAGS
        popf

        push   eax                     ;2nd argument is magic number
        push   ebx                     ;1st argument multiboot info pointer
        call   _Main                   ;Call _Main 
        add    esp, 8                  ;Cleanup 8 bytes pushed as arguments

        cli
endloop:
        hlt
        jmp   endloop

_Main:  
        ret                            ; Do nothing
```

The Multiboot loader (*GRUB*) generally loads in the first 8k of your file (whether *ELF* or flat binary), looks for the Multiboot header on a 32 bit boundary. If *bit 16* of the Multiboot header FLAG is clear, it assumes you are providing an *ELF* image. It then parses the *ELF* header to retrieve the information it needs to load your kernel file into memory. If *bit 16* is set then a complete Multiboot header is required so that the loader has the information to read your kernel into memory, perform initialization,and then call into your kernel.

You would then assemble your `init.s` to a flat binary with something like:

```
nasm -f bin -o init.bin init.s
```

## Using ELF with Multiboot

To tie in Jester's comments to your original question, you should have been able to boot with *ELF* and have it work, but it didn't because of one small detail. In your example you used this to make *init.bin*:

```
nasm -f elf32 -o init.bin  init.s
```

When using `-f elf32`, *NASM* generates object files (they aren't executable), that must be linked (with *LD* for example) to generate a final *ELF*(ELF32) executable. It would have probably worked if you had done the assemble and link processes with something like:

```
nasm -f elf32 init.s -o init.o 
ld -Ttext=0x100000 -melf_i386 -o init.bin init.o
```

Please note that when using `-f elf32` you must remove the *ORG* directive from *init.s*. The *ORG* directive only applies when using `-f bin`. Multiboot loaders will load us at physical address `0x100000` so we must make sure that the assembled and linked code are generated with that origin point. When using `-f elf32` we specify the entry point with `-Ttext=0x100000` on the linker (*LD*) command line. Alternatively the origin point can be set in a linker script.

## Using NASM/LD/OBJCOPY to Generate Flat Binary Images

It is possible to use *NASM*/*LD*/*OBJCOPY* together to produce a final flat binary image rather than using `-f bin` with *NASM*. If you remove the *ORG* directive from *init.s* and use these commands it should generate a flat binary *init.bin*:

```
nasm -f elf32 init.s -o init.o
ld -Ttext=0x100000 -melf_i386 -o init.elf init.o
objcopy -O binary init.elf init.bin
```

In this, *NASM* is told to generate *ELF32* objects. We assemble *init.s* into an *ELF* object file called *init.o*. We can then use the linker (*LD*) to generate an *ELF* executable from *init.o* called *init.elf*. We use a special program called *objcopy* to strip all the *ELF* headers off and generate a flat binary executable called *init.bin*.

This is a lot more involved than just using *NASM* with the `-f bin` option to generate the flat executable *init.bin*. Why bother then? With the method above you can tell *NASM* to generate debug information that can be utilized by *gdb* (the GNU debugger). If you attempt to use `-g`(enable debugging) with *NASM* using `-f bin` no debugging information gets generated. You can generate debug information by altering the assembly sequence this way:

```
nasm -g3 -F dwarf -f elf32 init.s -o init.o
ld -Ttext=0x100000 -melf_i386 -o init.elf init.o
objcopy -O binary init.elf init.bin
```

*init.o* will contain debug information (in *dwarf* format) that will be linked with *LD* into *init.elf* (which retains the debug information). Flat binaries don't contain debug information because they are stripped off when you use *objcopy* with `-O binary`. You can use *init.elf* if you enable the remote debugging facility in *QEMU* and use *GDB* for debugging. This debug info in *init.elf* provides information to the debugger that allows you to single step through your code, access variables and labels by name, see the source assembler code etc.

Besides generating debug information, there is another reason to use the *NASM*/*LD*/*OBJCOPY* process to generate a kernel binary. *LD* is much for configurable. *LD* allows a person to create linker scripts that allow you to better tune how things get laid out in the final binary. This can be useful for more complex kernels that may contain a mixture of code from different environments (C, Assembler etc). For a small toy kernel it may not be needed, but as a kernel grows in complexity the benefits of using a [linker script](http://wiki.osdev.org/Bare_Bones#Linking_the_Kernel) will become more evident.

## Remote debugging of QEMU with GDB

If you use the method in the previous section to generate debugging information inside an *ELF* executable (*init.elf*) you can launch *QEMU* and have it:

- Load the *QEMU* environment and halt the CPU at startup. From man page:

  > -S  Do not start CPU at startup (you must type 'c' in the monitor).
- Make *QEMU* listen for a *GDB* remote connection on localhost:1234 . From man page:

  > -s  Shorthand for -gdb tcp::1234, i.e. open a gdbserver on TCP port 1234.

Then you just have to launch *GDB* so that it:

- Launches *GDB* with our *ELF* executable (*init.elf*) with debug symbols and information
- Connects to localhost:1234 where *QEMU* is listening
- Sets up the debug layout of your choice
- Sets a break point to stop in our kernel (in this example *multiboot_entry*)

Here is an example of launching our kernel from the CD-ROM image *init.iso*, and launching *GDB* to connect to it:

```
qemu-system-x86_64 -cdrom ./init.iso -S -s &    
gdb init.elf \
        -ex 'target remote localhost:1234' \
        -ex 'layout src' \
        -ex 'layout regs' \
        -ex 'break multiboot_entry' \
        -ex 'continue'
```

You should be able to use *GDB* in much the same way as debugging a normal program. This assumes you will not be debugging a 16-bit program (kernel).

## Important Considerations

As Jester points out, when using Multiboot compliant loaders like *GRUB*, the CPU is in 32-bit protected mode (not 16-bit real mode). Unlike booting right from the BIOS, you won't be able to use 16-bit code including most of the PC-BIOS interrupts. If you need to be in real mode you would have to change back to real mode manually, or create a VM86 task (the latter isn't trivial).

This is an important consideration since some of the code you linked to in MikeOS is 16-bit.

Comment: If using ELF, the file must be a fully linked executable, not an object file (this is the actual cause of the error message). Also, the loader will invoke the kernel in 32 bit protected mode, so the code better not be 16 bit real mode. Thanks for writing it up, he didn't believe me :D

Comment: @Jester - What I "didn't believe" was your assertion that "For a multiboot kernel you need a 32 bit ELF executable".   The answer shows this is clearly not the case - what I was missing was the load location header parts.

Comment: @Michael Petch - TYVM, this is extremely helpful.

Comment: @BadZen I meant, **if** you are using ELF (and from your post it was clear you were), it must be an executable. It can not be an object because grub won't recognize it (hence the error) and because objects usually have unresolved addresses so they won't work even with a full header (unless it's PIC). And the code must be 32 bit protected mode in any case.

Comment: @BadZen @Jester is correct, when you compile ELF you need to link (you can use LD for that). I didn't put that in my answer since you seemed keen on using a flat binary. Had you wanted to use ELF, the reason yours wasn't working was because the output from nasm with `-f elf32` creates an object file not a executable. To get ELF working you would have to do `nasm -f elf32 init.s -o init.o` then link to an executable with `ld -melf_i386 init.o -o init.bin`

Comment: @BadZen : I have cleaned up my answer with additional information that might be of value to you or others who read this question. It now includes information on debugging a kernel (even one loaded via grub)